# Enzyme Assay - pectinase

Tags: acid-base, biochemistry, chemical-biology, spectrophotometry, enzymes

I am working on Enzyme Assay.I assayed the enzyme in different buffers from $pH\ 1-12.5$ However,the enzyme has good activities starting from $pH\ 1-10.5$ Is that possible to have enzyme activity in such broad range ?